# C# - How to populate a DropDownList in EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, gridview, edititemtemplate

Here, I have a DropDownList in the EditItemTemplate:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequestedBy" SortExpression="RequestedBy">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ReqUserDDL" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems ="True" DataSourceID="ReqUsersDataS" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name") %>' >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReqUsersDataS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:itassetmgmtConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Firstname + Lastname AS Name FROM Users"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RequestedBy") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

However, I keep getting this error:

`DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.`

Is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Eval` instead of `Bind`. `Bind` is for read and/or write, `Eval` is read-only.

**EDIT:** Eval/Bind error is not from from the ReqUsersDataS DataSource. It is trying to for a column named 'Name' on the data source of the GridView that has the TemplateField you showed. You just need to make sure that other data source has column named 'Name'.

Comment: 'ReqUserDDL' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: Well, you need to make sure whatever value you want selected actually exists in the DropDownList. If the DropDownList has the values 10, 20, 30 and you set the SelectedValue to 40, you wiil get that error.